# I want to integrate SSO between ASP.net webapp and Drupal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-sign-on, drupal-8

I want to integrate SSO between ASP.net and Drupal using OpenID

Comment: I am doing this first so I don't have an Idea please guide me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.